# Trying to understand my IEnumerable and why I can't use .ToList()

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core, async-await

I currently have the following method for one of my data objects repo patterns:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<DropDownList>> GetDropDownListNoTracking()
{
    return await context.TouchTypes
       .AsNoTracking()
       .Where(s => s.IsActive)
       .Select(s => new DropDownList()
       {
           Id = s.Id,
           Name = s.Description
       }).ToListAsync();
}
```

When I call it in my page view :

```
private IList<DropDownList> TouchTypeList { get; set; }   
private async Task LoadDropDownAsync()
{  
    TouchTypeList = await _unitOfWork.TouchType.GetDropDownListNoTracking();
}
```

I'm trying to understand why I can't just do a `GetDropDownListNoTracking().ToList()`
but instead, it wants me to cast  : `(IList<DropDownList>)`.

I can easily just change the property to fix this but I would assume `.ToList` would work here?

I'm mostly just trying to understand this so I can do it the correct way.

Comment: Note that you are forcing the (async) enumeration of your selection into a list in `GetDropDownListNoTracking`, but returning it as an `IEnumerable<DropDownList>` (after an `await`).  As a result, the consumers of `GetDropDownListNoTracking` have the urge to call `.ToList` on it (as your code does).  That `ToList` code is superfluous and expensive - it makes a copy of the already fabricated list you are returning.  Unless `LoadDropDownAsync` needs _List-y-ness_, skip the `.ToList` call

Comment: ​​Why are you returning a `Task<IEnumerable<DropDownList>>` instead of a `Task<IList<DropDownList>>`? What's the benefit of this? Or it's just for the aesthetics, because `IEnumerable`s are cooler that `IList`s?

Answer (score 7):

`GetDropDownListNoTracking` returns `Task<IEnumerable<DropDownList>>`, not `IEnumerable<DropDownList>`, so you'd have to do:

```
private async Task LoadDropDownAsync()
{  
    TouchTypeList = (await _unitOfWork.TouchType.GetDropDownListNoTracking()).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Calling `ToList` on an enumerable that you know is really always a list is a waste of CPU cycles, and points to a poor choice of return type for your method. The simplest solution is to change your method to:

```
public async Task<IList<DropDownList>> GetDropDownListNoTracking()
{
    return await context.TouchTypes
       .AsNoTracking()
       .Where(s => s.IsActive)
       .Select(s => new DropDownList()
       {
           Id = s.Id,
           Name = s.Description
       }).ToListAsync();
}
```

*Although I personally would use `IReadOnlyList` instead.*